# React JS synchronous handling of array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am very new to React JS and in some ways javascript here is the problem I am trying to solve. I have a function in a component that looks like the below that iterates through an array of numbers:

```html
 playerSequence: function() {
        var game = this;
        this.state.game.sequence.map(function(currNum){
            console.log(currNum);
              switch(currNum){
                  case 1:
                      game.handleBlue();
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      game.handleYellow();
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      game.handleGreen();
                      break;
                  case 4:
                      game.handleRed();
                      break;

              }
          })
    },
```

Each function call has a setTimeout that waits a period of time and renders a light and then switches off the light after this.props.wait ms. Below is an example:

```html
var RedOn = React.createClass({
    mixins: [TimerMixin],
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.setTimeout(function(){this.props.handleRed()}, this.props.wait);
    },
    handleRed: function() {
        this.props.handleRed()
    },
renderstuff
});
```

What I would like is for each pass through the map array to wait until the function call is finished and then continue. As it is right now they all go off at the same time. I am sure I am not fully understanding the nature of node, react or a combo of both. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only want to iterate over the array, use `.forEach` instead of `.map`.

Comment: Good tip, thanks, foreach I suppose is going to be faster than map for just iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the React docs, `componentDidMount` is ***Invoked once***, only on the client (not on the server), **immediately after the initial rendering occurs.**

So it would make sense that they would all fire at once. The other problem is that `setTimeout` is invoked as soon as its called, which means if you pass some time in milliseconds to each function, `map` will simply invoke them all at once, not apply them sequentially. If you wanted to keep using map, you should declare a variable to store previous time applied, and add it into each timeout.

```
var previousTime = 0; 

["foo", "bar", "baz"].map( function(e) { 
    setTimeout( function() { console.log(e); }, 1000 + previousTime); 
previousTime += 1000; });
```

Here's a trivial example of what I'm describing. Try running this in a console to see the result. Every time you call "setTimeout" you add the time to the `previousTime` variable, so that each element waits an additional second before showing.

At the end of the day, even with all the abstractions offered by React, remember **It'sJustJavaScript™**

Comment: This exactly fixed my problem, or at least it is working as intended! Thanks a ton. I was thinking I would have to go down the promises path but this is a nice quick fix.